# Proving a equation from a System of 5 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

This equation emerged while I was solving a geometry problem, which was equivalent to proving $x+n=m$.

Solve the system of polynominal equations where $x,y,z,m,n,l$ are positive reals.

$$
\begin{cases}
yz=nl\\                                                             
x^2=m(m+n)\\
(x+z)^2=m(m+n+l)\\
(x+z)^2+z^2=(m+n)^2\\
(x+z)^2+(y+z)^2=(x+y)^2
\end{cases}
$$

Through complex calculation, I solved the equation for $z$, which gave me $x=\frac{\sqrt {7}+1}{3}z$, $m=\frac{\sqrt {7}+1}{2}z$, $n=\frac{\sqrt {7}+1}{6}z$.

However, this way seemed a bit complex, and solving it for other variables did not seem simpler either.

Is there any simple way to prove $x+n=m$ without calculating each value?

[An Link to the Original Geometry Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620922/proving-aeap-pd-in-a-certain-right-triangle)

Comment: What was exactly the original problem?

Comment: Angle $C$ is a right angle in triangle $ABC$, and the incircle is tangent to lines $AC,CB,BA$ in $E,D,F$. $AD$ meets the incircle in point $P$, and the angle of $BPC$ is right. Prove that $AE+AP=PD$. While I think that there is a geometric solution to this, I am also interested in a easier algebraic solution. (I am not very famaliar with the english words for geometry, so excuse any errors that I have made.)

Comment: You should seek a geometric answer to the problem, as the problem itself is geometric. I understand your desire to find an algebraic solution, but since this is a geometry problem, you may not find such a solution.

Comment: @K.Jiang Is it all right if I asked the geometry question in a seperate question? I am just curious about the algebraic way.

Comment: I don't see why not. I just want you to receive the easiest answer possible (algebra can get very messy).

Comment: (1) $x+n=m\iff x-m=-n$; (2) $x^2=m(m+n)\iff (x-m)(x+m)=mn$ Hence, from (1) and (2), $x=-2m$

Comment: @Piquito Note that $x+n=m$ is not given. We have to prove it. Also, your equation has the solution $3x=2m$ as well.

Comment: @ChadShin: What I did was a remark: if $x+n=m$ true then .... I shall pay attention for a while to your problem. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Your attention is appreciated.